# Fields are not moving up when dial pad comes up

Tags: android

On certain pages of my Android project, fields are not moving up when the dial pad comes up. Why? How can I get them to move?

Comment: by posting an answerable question?

Answer (score 2):

Set your activities `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. [See this for details.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)